# Error with Autogenerated file BuildConfig.java - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I suddenly have an error in my Android eclipse project.  This is after a hard shutdown while running eclipse, so that may have something to do with it.  I clean the project and then do a build.  I get the following error on the BuildConfig.class file that is autogenerated in the /gen dir:

```
The type android.content.Context cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I did notice that in my build configuration the JRE was stated to be missing.  I have since fixed this problem, but still get the error.  Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by going to "Fix project properties".  Right click project-->android tools.

Do not know what caused this error.

Comment: FWIW, I also had this problem when compiling an Android project library in Eclipse after a BSOD, but also after copying an existing project that uses that library.  I don't know which caused the problem, but I didn't notice anything until I copied the project. Anyway, rather than trying Fix project properties, I just exited Eclipse and then re-started it.  The problem went away.  It may be that on coming up Eclipse does the equivalent of a "Fix project properties."  If that is true, then it may have been the copy project that caused the issue, since it was started after the BSOD and looked OK.