# The type android.content.Context cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sup

I got solution(it worked for someone) for my problem:

[Error with Autogenerated file BuildConfig.java - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025538/error-with-autogenerated-file-buildconfig-java-android)

Actually I do not have idea how to do this in Sybase unwired platform/eclipse:

**"Fix project properties". Right click project-->android tools.**

Note: I have generated code in Sybase unwired platfrom V2.1.3 for Android device.After this automatic code generation I'm getting this error, in following method:

The type android.content.Context cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
public static synchronized void setApplication(com.sybase.mobile.Application app)
{
    com.sybase.sup.client.mbs.RegistryUtil.setApplicationContext(app.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
    initialize();
}
```

How to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding jar from Android SDK path...cleared the error. :)

Josh Edit: 
Basically I copied the file android.jar from my computer and added it to the path of my Sap Mobile Platform project,  which is running on a remote virtual machine. 
These are the detailed steps (We all love detailed steps):

go to:
YourAndroidSDKPath\sdk\platforms\android-17   (instead of 17 go to your version number)

...and copy the file android.jar somewhere else

Now, go to your SMP project, highlight the red "app.getInstance().getApplicationContext()" 
code where the error is, so that a yellow popup appears, with a hyperlink to "Fix Path"

Go to the Library tab, click on add external JAR, and browse to the android.jar file that
you copied before.

Voila!!

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you did for others that'll have the same problem as you?

Comment: What I did to fix the problem was: right click the project -> Properties -> Android -> Selected Android version in "Project build target" -> OK. If there is Android version already selected, select another one, and if needed to the steps again to select the previous version.

Comment: fixed my problem too. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Right click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Android Clathpath Container -> Select your project from avaliable projects in your workspace -> Finish.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem.  The solution ended up being that I was using the Android SDK when I needed the Google APIs SDK.  Right click project > Android > Select one of the Google APIs checkboxes, then clean and build.